# How does the OnTouch event behave?

Tags: android, multi-touch

If there are multiple fingers on the device, does the onTouch-listener run once for every finger, or it runs once per event(finger down, move, etc..) and include every active touch pointer?

And if

```
(e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
```

how do I know which pointer is moving currently?

```
final int pointerIndex = e.getActionIndex();
pointerID = e.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
```

Always gives back 0(while MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) for some reason..

Comment: I already read through [that](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html), but still don't know how to get an ID back from the event if the action is ACTION_MOVE.. Since I tried what was written down in the ACTION_POINTER_UP, but I always got 0 in ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you get these events:

1. `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`
   for the FIRST touch on the screen
2. `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`
   for all non-primary touches
3. `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`
   for the last touch up
4. `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP`
   for every non-primary touch up
5. `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`
   everytime anyone of the touched fingers moves
   here you have to go through all figers and check if the coordinates have changed

do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT; //index of this pointer

    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //your first touch on the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //one of the touches has moved
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ev.getPointerCount(); i++)
            {
                //The pointer id is ev.getPointerId(i);
                //for loop through all touches
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //your last touch has gone up
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //non-primary pointer has gone down
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            //non-primary pointer has gone up
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope this helps you a little bit :)

Comment: so in ACTION_MOVE I basically have to check every pointer? Can't say I'm surprised... basically in an onTouch function the MotionEvent contains all of the currently active pointers?

Comment: Thank you :) and yes, you got it ;)  when one pointer moves, you have to check all to see which has moved. (A little bit unoptimized...)